# How to update axis labels when animating with a Matplotlib slider?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating heatplot of a 3-by-500 matrix and wish to advance through the columns by means of a horizontal slider, incrementing, say 20 columns at a time. A vertical colorbar appears to the right of the heaplot in each frame. What I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

M=np.random.rand(3,300)
win_size=20
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=.2, right=None, top=.9, wspace=.2, hspace=.2)
ax_divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = ax_divider.append_axes('right', size='7%', pad='2%')

ax_time=fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])


spos = Slider(ax_time, 'Time',valinit=0,valmin=0,valmax=M.shape[1],valstep=win_size)
def update_graph(val):
   start=spos.val
   stop=spos.val+win_size
   if stop<M.shape[1]:
       ax.cla
       heatmap=ax.imshow(M[:,start:stop],vmin=0, 
       vmax=1,aspect='auto')
       cb = fig.colorbar(heatmap, cax=cax, orientation='vertical')

spos.on_changed(update_graph)
spos.set_val(0)
plt.show()
```

I can't seem to recall how to update my horizontal axis labels correctly. Specifically, as written, this will show the x-axis varying from 0 to 20 for each frame. What I want is the first frame to be labelled 0 to 20, the second frame 20 to 40, and so on. I also want to be able to specify the number of ticks to appear in each frame. So, if I specified 5 ticks, then the first frame has axis tickmarks at 0,5,10,15,20, the second has tickmarks at 20,25,30,35,40, and so on. Shouldn't this be easy to accomplish using `set_xticks` and `set_xticklabels`?

Answer (score 0):

To set the number of xticks, say 10, use `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(10))` after `ax` has been created.

To update the labels, I inserted these lines at the end of the update function:

```
    ticks=ax.get_xticks()
    labels=[str(start+ticks[i]) for i in range(len(ticks))]
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```